# strange reboot log

Tags: shutdown, reboot, log

I am sure I had shut off my laptop at 02:50, turned off AC, and I turned on it at 12:47. What does those "still running" means?

During the last power off progress, I occurred an hang. I am searching the reason about that "slow shutdown".

```
▶ last reboot
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-62-generic Tue Feb  7 12:47  still running 
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-62-generic Mon Feb  6 16:30  still running 
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-62-generic Mon Feb  6 13:41  still running 
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-62-generic Sun Feb  5 19:27  still running 
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-62-generic Sun Feb  5 11:47 - 12:58  (01:11)
```

here is some lines in the /var/log/kern.log file.

```
Feb  7 02:50:12 eexp-XPS-L421X NetworkManager[1211]: <info>  [1486407012.0219] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed bound -> bound
Feb  7 03:09:29 eexp-XPS-L421X gnome-session-binary[2050]: Entering running state
Feb  7 12:47:59 eexp-XPS-L421X kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

my cups-browsed.service is disabled.

```
● cups-browsed.service - Make remote CUPS printers available locally
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups-browsed.service; disabled; vendor pr
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the man page

> The pseudo user reboot logs in each time the system is rebooted.  Thus last reboot will show a log of all the reboots since the log file was created.

The reboot user hasn't logged out since you've rebooted, this is normal.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1146476/what-does-still-running-mean-linux